# Json From Facebook and Unity

Tags: c#, json, facebook, unity-game-engine

I have a json returned from the Facebook SDK in unity that looks like this:

```
{"name":"Name_of_person", "id":"989988988"}
```

I've taken a look at the raw JSON and this is what it looks like after I submit a query for that information via the Graph API.

So far I am trying to deserialize the json as such:

```
void DealWithProfileInfo(IGraphResult result){


    Dictionary<string,string> profile = JSON.Deserialize (result.RawResult) as Dictionary<string,string>;

    scoresText.text = profile ["first_name"];
    idText.text = profile["id"];
```

DealWithProfileInfo being my callback method from the FB.API call.

for some reason none of the information gets displayed and I am not sure why.

Am I missing something? Or maybe I am parsing the data wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `profile ["name"]` since `"name"` is the token that appears in the JSON?

Comment: You should declare and cast to `Dictionary<string,object>` instead of `Dictionary<string,string>` then convert that `object` to `string`

Comment: @HamzaHasan Thanks man! This fixed it :-)

Comment: Its good yo see that your problem is solve, so I'm pasting this comment as answer, please mark it as answer so that other people also get benefit from this. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is my personal experience that whenever I mess up with Facebook SDK or any other JSON in Unity3d, then what ever the hierarchy of JSON would be, it always returns `Dictionary<string,object>`. So developer have to come through that stairs

So in your case you should declare and cast to `Dictionary<string,object>` instead of `Dictionary<string,string>` then convert that `object` to `string`.